# I am always confused when taking squareroots during integration any help?

Tags: integration, square-numbers

[image]

Hello in the picture is a solved problem from my textbook i understand it all except why they choose sec& = sqrt(5)
It should have included the negative value also

Comment: Look at the fifth line. Square root is always nonnegative.

Comment: You're right that $s = -\sqrt{5}$ is also a solution to $s^2 = 5$, but we need to think about the context of the problem. In the context of the problem $\sec(\theta)$ is nonnegative since it is the square root of a real quantity.

Comment: Very clear thank you guys so much.

Comment: I also had the thought that since we are using an angle @ as a parameter for substitution it is needed that g(@) be continuous so that the domain of f(x) can be covered continuously

Comment: prets if we allow it to take the negative value then the output of g(@) would not correspond to the domain of f(x) is that also a good reason?

Comment: See the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write symbols and formulas.

Comment: Yes. There are many reasons $-\sqrt{5}$ is irrelevant to this particular problem. For instance, $-\sqrt{5} + 2 < 0$ so the logarithm in the final answer would have a negative argument.

Comment: It's outside the scope of the provided text, but you may employ [another substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) to circumvent dealing with the square root. For instance, $y=\frac{2z}{4-z^2}$ gives$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+4y^2}\,dy=2\int_0^{\sqrt5-1}\frac{(4+z^2)^2}{(4-z^2)^3}\,dz\quad.$$

Comment: user170231 thank you.

Comment: @ Hfdssdjns, when we put $y=\frac{1}{2} \tan \theta$, we should take $\frac{-\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. So $\sec \theta>0$ and hence $\sec \theta=\sqrt 5$.